# How to allocate a region of memories which similar VirtualAlloc?

Tags: linux, virtualalloc

I was looking for a method of allocating memories on Linux which similar VirtualAlloc on Windows. Requirements are:

1. Size of memories block to allocate is 2^16.
2. Address of memories block is larger than 0x0000ffff
3. Address of memories block must have last 16 bits are zero.

On Windows because lower limit of application address (lpMinimumApplicationAddress) we have (2) obvious right. From (1), (2) and system rules we also achieved (3).

Thanks for helping.

Comment: @Ignacio: Typically for DMA.  This is (indirectly) the reason that direct I/O functions often require aligned buffers.

Comment: What is user code doing allocating memory for DMA?

Comment: @Ignacio: I just told you: direct (unbuffered) I/O.  On Windows that would be `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING`.  Not sure exactly how it's done on Linux, but the kernel just locks the buffer you provide and uses it for DMA, instead of copying from a DMA bounce buffer.  "Zero-copy I/O" is in high demand.

Comment: @Ignacio: For #3, I'm trying to implement memory pooling. I can get address to the chunk by (blockPtr & 0xffff0000). This is useful when deallocate a block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `posix_memalign()`:

```
void *ptr;
int memalign_err = posix_memalign(&ptr, 1UL << 16, 1UL << 16);

if (memalign_err) {
    fprintf(stderr, "posix_memalign: %s\n", strerror(memalign_err));
} else {
    /* ptr is valid */
}
```

The first `1UL << 16` is the alignment, and the second is the size.

When you're done with the block you pass it to `free()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try `mmap(..., MAP_ANONYMOUS, ...)`

You'll get an address which is aligned to a page boundary.  For more stringent alignment than that, you probably need to allocate extra and pick an address inside your larger block than is correctly aligned.

Comment: Thanks but how to obtain (2) and (3) with this?.

Comment: @Giang: #2 happens, the OS reserves the first few pages of memory to help detect NULL pointers.  For #3, if you allocate 2**17 bytes, you are guaranteed to have a block of 2**16 starting on a 2**16 boundary somewhere in the allocated region.  Or, as @sherpya says, you can request an address that meets your requirements.  If it's not already in use, you'll get the exact address you requested.

Comment: Thanks but do so seems like too waste. Can we tell mmap the lower limit of memory address we want?.

Comment: @Giang: Have you read the man page for `mmap`?  It's actually quite descriptive.

Comment: Yes, I read it even before asking this question. Hint params not really is a lower limit.

Comment: @Giang: Allocating twice as much as you need doesn't waste anything, because you can use the aligned block and give the other portions back with `munmap`.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: I tried mmap(0, 65536 * 2, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0). Sadly it return an address which have last 12 bits zero, not 16 bits. What wrong?.

Comment: @Giang: Nothing's wrong, now you need to get the subset of that large block that IS aligned.  Like [this](http://ideone.com/Bxzm7).

Answer (score 0):

you can ask a specific address to mmap, it may fail for some specific addresses, but generally it works

Comment: But I do this allocation many times, I can't predict what specific addresses are suitable.

Comment: vm.mmap_min_addr via proc interface, but it's a global kernel setting